# Specify the Poincaré line

Tags: geometry

Please help me to solve this question.

question:

what is the Poincaré line through the points (3,4)  and (1,2).

Comment: Do you mean "what is the Poincaré line through the points $(3,4)$ and $(1,2)$?"

Comment: yes.Thanks a lot for your consideration.

Comment: @amWhy :)${~~~~~~}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** In the Poincare upper half plane, lines are of two types: intersections of vertical lines with $y>0$, and intersections of circles centered on the $x$ axis with $y>0$. Your two points are not vertically alligned. So set up $(x-a)^2+y^2=r^2$, plug in your two points, and solve for $a,r$.

Comment: +Thanks for your hint.