# Specify the Poincaré line1

Tags: geometry

question:

what is the Poincaré line through the points (3,4) and (1,2)?

Please help me to solve this question.

Comment: Same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344858/specify-the-poincare-line/345150#345150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

I am giving you a general formula in which you can find a certain Poincae line passing through $(x_1,y_1),~(x_2,y_2)$ whenever $x_1\neq x_2$. $$_cL_r=\{(x,y)\mid(x-c)^2+y^2=r^2\},~c=\frac{y_2^2-y_1^2+x_2^2-x_1^2}{2(x_2-x_1)},~r=\sqrt{(x_1-c)^2+y_1^2}$$

Your line is the same as below:

[image]

Comment: Nice work! +1 ;-)

Comment: @flashdesign: You're Welcome!